# Elementary number theory problem and FindInstance

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

Find $\{ m,n \} \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m \neq n$ and $m^n = n^m$.

This has (unordered) solutions $\{ 2, 4 \}$ and $\{ -2, -4 \}$, as can be easily checked.

I'm of course hoping for an analytic approach, but the direct method in *Mathematica* does not find any solutions:

```
FindInstance[m^n == n^m \[And] m != n, {m, n}, Integers]
```

I've tried several variants, including `Solve`, taking `Log` of both sides, and so on... and none worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we assume `m>0, n>0`,then the equation is equivalent to `Log[m]/m==Log[n]/n`.
We consider the function `f[x]=Log[x]/x`.

```
Solve[D[Log[x]/x, x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> E}}`

```
Plot[{Log[x]/x, 1/E, Log[4]/4, Log[2]/2}, {x, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

It is easy to see that `f[x]` increasing from $0$ to $E$ and decreasing from $E$ to $\infty$, so we need to set `m>=E>=n` in such equation.

```
Solve[{Log[m]/m == Log[n]/n, m >= E >= n}, PositiveIntegers]
```

> `{{m -> 4, n -> 2}}`

Comment: Oh... nice.  Of course based on the Youtube video, but it was a good idea to map that to code.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: By the monotonous, `m=n` is the only solution when `{m,n}>E` or `0<{m,n}<E` ,that is why we only need to consider the case in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a weird way to do it with `NMinimize` - the stuff with `Quiet/Check/Boole` is to work around the `0^0` and `0^-x` issue. I found `NMinimize` wouldn't avoid these cases even if you added `m != n, m != 0, n != 0` to the constraints:

```
f[m_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := 
  Quiet[Check[0/Boole[m != n] + (m^n - n^m)^2, 10^20]]

{err, sol} = NMinimize[{f[m, n], m < 0, n < 0}, {n ∈ Integers, m ∈ Integers}]
With[{v = Values[sol]}, (f @@ v == 0 && Unequal @@ v)]

(* {0., {n -> -4, m -> -2}} True *)
```

Change `m < 0, n < 0` to `m > 0, n > 0` to get the positive solution.

Comment: Thanks ($+1$) but I should have mentioned that I solved the problem numerically too.  Of course I'm seeking an *analytic* method.  Let's see if someone has a clever approach to this.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm not sure an analytic approach even exists -  Diophantine equations are hard and usually boil down to just checking inputs - i.e numerical approaches. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Exponential_Diophantine_equations)

Answer (score 1):

With variable restrictions up to 100, FindInstance and Reduce do the job.

```
FindInstance[{m^n == n^m, m != n, 0 < m < 100, 0 < n < 100}, {m, n}, Integers]

(*   {{m -> 2, n -> 4}}   *)

Reduce[{m^n == n^m, m != n, -100 < m < 0, -100 < n < 0}, {m, n}, Integers]

(*   (m == -4 && n == -2) || (m == -2 && n == -4)   *)
```

Comment: Hah... halfway between numerical search and algorithmic solution!  ($+1$).  Let's still wait a while to see if anyone finds an analytic approach.  After all, there are Youtube clips on how to solve this problem, but they all involve creativity at the human level.

Answer (score 1):

Yet an other answer. Plot3D of m^n - n^m == 0 shows, you can divide the (m,n)-area into four quadrants around {m,n} = {E,E}. Three of them can be easily solved. The fourth can be proofen to have only solutions for m == n.

```
Plot3D[{0, m^n - n^m}, {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}, PlotRange -> 1]

Reduce[{0 < n < E, m^n == n^m}, {m, n}, Integers]
(*   (m == 1 && n == 1) || (m == 2 && n == 2) || (m == 4 && n == 2)   *)

Reduce[{0 < m < E, m^n == n^m}, {m, n}, Integers]
(*   (m == 1 && n == 1) || (m == 2 && n == 2) || (m == 2 && n == 4)   *)

red1 = Reduce[{m^n == n^m, E < n, E < m}, {m, n}, Reals]
(*   m > E && n == E^-ProductLog[-1, -(Log[m]/m)]   *)

Reduce[E^-ProductLog[-1, -(Log[m]/m)] == m, m, Integers]
(*   m \[Element] Integers && m >= 3   *)
```

For all m >=3, E^-ProductLog[...] is equal m, therefore n == m.

Comment: Helpful... thanks.  ($+1$)